# How to cancel jQuery UI dialog open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, show

I have the following:

```
container.dialog().bind('dialogopen', function(event, ui)
  {
     ...
     if (someCondition)
     {
         $(this).dialog('close'); // the dialog is not closed!
     }
  }
```

How I should make it work?

Unfortunately there is no 'beforeopen' event to be hooked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you need to bind the event **before** it happens.  Currently you're calling `.dialog()` which opens the dialog (unless `autoOpen: false` is a provided option).  This means before your [`.bind(....)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) runs, the event already occured.  The solution is to just bind *before* the event happens, like this:

```
container.bind('dialogopen', function(event, ui) {
  if (someCondition) {
     $(this).dialog('close'); // the dialog is not closed!
  }
}).dialog(); //.dialog() fires "dialogopen" as part of it's execution
```

[You can view a demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/KdxYd/), it'll prevent the dialog from opening, or rather it *does* open, but instantly closes before the UI thread updates, so to the user, it never opened.

This works because [the `dialogopen` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open) is fired on the element you turned into a dialog (not the dialog container)...it doesn't matter that the dialog itself is created later, this is just a DOM element listening to events.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [autoOpen](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-autoOpen) (set it to `false`) to keep it hidden until you confirm someCondition. Then call `.dialog("open")` …

Comment: Yep. I thought of that but since it is a plugin I cannot be sure who the caller of .dialog('open') can be. Maybe I should reconsider my design.

Answer (score 0):

The open event in dialog is like 'beforeopen'.