# Prevent a div dialog popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Got a issue hope someone could help.

My web application is running now and a postback will trigger server side ScriptManager to pop up a div dialog on front page. By default this popup div dialog is hidden and it will only be appeared by server side ScriptManager 
like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
                                        "showDate", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(\"#myDate\").css(\"visibility\",\"visible\"); $(window).load(function () {$(\"#myDate\").dialog(\"open\");});</script>", false);
```

What if I cannot change server side code, is there any way to modify or add some javascript code in the html page to prevent this?

---

In short, now server side ScriptManager will call **.dialog(\"open\")** to pop the div, is there any client side way to prevent this? I cannot change server side now.

---

Edit: By default the div is hidden, once click on a page img, postback will trigger server side code below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
                                        "showDate", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(\"#myDate\").css(\"visibility\",\"visible\"); $(window).load(function () {$(\"#myDate\").dialog(\"open\");});</script>", false);
```

Then in HTML page I have

```
$('#plotTimeY').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top" },
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 2000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 2000
        }
    });
```

Now without code change on server side(I cannot), is there any client side way to prevent the div dialog popup?

Appreciate!

THANKS TO J Santosh

Simply changing div ID will work. This solution is more likely specified to my issue but not a general solution. Any other comment or discussion about container control between server side and client side is more than welcome!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135721/how-to-cancel-jquery-ui-dialog-open

Comment: That is a good answer but does not work on my situation. I tried that code but it does not prevent popup but closes dialog after it popup.

Comment: @Pugazh Thanks, any other hint?

Comment: change the `ID` of the div.

Comment: @JSantosh Yea...change ID works...so tricky....Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help :) Can't post it answer because it is not worth an answer , so just update your question (Add Solved in title) and add answer at end of body . @Windtalker

Comment: @JSantosh Updated, again thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can always hide that element #mydate in your css file by:

```
#mydate {
    display:none !important;
}
```

But I can't tell what kind of event listeners that .dialog() method adds. 
As a secure way you can close the dialog just after a timeout if a

```
$("#mydate").dialog("close");}
```

is available.

Comment: I modified my description, $("#mydate").dialog("close");} does not work